# Best way to allow space in password

Tags: c#, whitespace, kerberos

What's the best way to allow spaces in password.there could be multiple spaces in password. I am capturing the password (`NewUserpassword`) in a textbox and then running a command like below:

```
" /kadmin -q 'cpw -pw " + NewUserPassword + " " + UserName + "'"
```

It works fine if there is no space in `NewUserpassword`. How to solve this?

Comment: What process is the code starting?

Comment: Does it work if you wrap the password with quotation marks?

Comment: code is starting as C# and then it calls kadmin in a method to talk to unix machines.

Comment: " +NewUserPassword + "is already in double qoutes

Comment: Have you tried: `" /kadmin -q 'cpw -pw \"" + NewUserPassword + "\" " + UserName + "'"`

Comment: What is running the Directory service which Kerberos is leveraging?  Is it Active Directory, or some other?